# Provision a new worker node in kubernetes cluster in case of failure

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, amazon-eks

I have just started out understanding kubernetes basics(even though I haven't implemented it practically) and I have some doubt in it.

Suppose my kubernetes cluster has one master node and two worker nodes( Suppose I am leveraging AWS EKS). If both worker nodes get failed due to different reasons, does EKS has this ability to spin up a new worker node? If not, is there any way to achieve this?

I also read this feature is not available in AWS but it is there in GCP. How exactly is this achieved?

Resource online are not very clear to me. Please help me to understand this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're using Amazon EKS you can run the [node-problem-detector](https://github.com/kubernetes/node-problem-detector) and [draino](https://github.com/planetlabs/draino) to automatically replace worker nodes when they "fail". You could also run the cluster-autoscaler which provisions new nodes when there are pending pods which could occur if a node suddenly went dark. Worker nodes that are part of an ASG, e.g. a managed node group, will be automatically replaced when the underlying hardware fails.